# Segmentation fault in vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is a code that I wrote for a Topcoder SRM. However there is a segmentation fault here that I cannot figure out. Can you help me figure it out?

The problem is -

This task is about the scoring in the first phase of the die-game Yahtzee, where five dice are used. The score is determined by the values on the upward die faces after a roll. The player gets to choose a value, and all dice that show the chosen value are considered active. The score is simply the sum of values on active dice.
Say, for instance, that a player ends up with the die faces showing 2, 2, 3, 5 and 4. Choosing the value two makes the dice showing 2 active and yields a score of 2 + 2 = 4, while choosing 5 makes the one die showing 5 active, yielding a score of 5.
Your method will take as input a vector  toss, where each element represents the upward face of a die, and return the maximum possible score with these values.

Constraints -

toss will contain five elements exactly. 
 Each element will be between 1 and 6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class YahtzeeScore
{
  public:
  int maxPoints(vector<int> toss);
};

int YahtzeeScore::maxPoints(vector <int> toss)
{ 
  vector<int> ret;
  vector <int>::iterator v = toss.begin();
  vector<int>::iterator w = toss.begin();
  for (;v != toss.end(); v++)
  {
    int s=0;
    for (;w != toss.end(); w++)
    {
      if ( w!=v && *w==*v) s++;
    }
     ret.push_back(s);
  }

  vector<int>::iterator it = ret.begin();
  for (; it!=ret.end(); it++)
  {
    if (*v>*(v+1))
    {
      int temp = *v;
      *v = *(v+1);
      *(v+1)=temp;
    }
  } 
  return ret[4];
}


int main()
{
  YahtzeeScore ob;
  vector<int> something;
  vector<int>::iterator it = something.begin();
  while (it != something.end())
  {
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    something.push_back(a);
  }
  cout << ob.YahtzeeScore::maxPoints(something);
}
```

Comment: You don't re-initialize `w = toss.begin();` in every `for (;v != toss.end(); v++)` so the `w` iteration works properly only for the forst `v` loop.

Comment: In `main()`, you are doing `push_back` into the vector you are iterating through. That invalidates the iterator. (Also, what is the point of the iterator there? There vector starts empty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You should run it through a debugger.

This bit of code in main():

```
vector<int>::iterator it = something.begin();
while (it != something.end())
```

`it` will always be something.end() as something is empty. This means it never reads any input, which means you pass a empty vector to `maxPoints`. Neither of `maxPoints` loops will run as `toss` is empty and `ret` is empty. so `ret[4]` will cause a segfault.

As you know you want 5 inputs, just use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    something.push_back(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line `if (*v>*(v+1))`,  `v` is pointing to the `end` so you can't dereference it.

I guess you meant `it` rather than `v`, however that still needs work as `*(it+1)` will be invalid if `it` is pointing to one-before-the-end.

Also you should checkthe size of `ret` before just doing `ret[4]`. Or do `ret.at(4)` so at least you get an exception instead of a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is in this block:

```
while (it != something.end())
{
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  something.push_back(a);
}
```

First time the check is made, `it == something.end()` since `something` is empty.

You pass the empty object to `ob.YahtzeeScore::maxPoints()`, which tries to get the 5-th item from an empty vector (`return ret[4]`), which causes the segmentation violation.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple loop `for( int face=1; face<6; face++)` and scan 6 times the five faces for those equal `face`. Sum them up and store the maximum sum found. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Vector something is not intialized, this caused segfault at return ret[4].

```
vector<int> something;
vector<int>::iterator it = something.begin();
while (it != something.end())
```

This loop never run because vector something is empty and it points to something.end(),
and loop endup with 0 elements in something.
Than you call maxPoints considering something contains at least 5 elements.
Since something contains nothing, `return ret[4];` is incorrect and you got segfaul.
Suggestion:
- there is clear precondition for maxPoints: toss.size() == 5. Use assert
- I would suggest to use `maxPoints(const vector<int> & toss);`, this will eliminate unnecessary copy.